# Infer type from union type key

Tags: typescript

I have a type alias that uses a union of literal types for the key:

```
type Type = {
  [key in 'a' | 'b']: string
}
```

However, TypeScript fails to infer the type correctly when I do this:

```
const object: Type = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => ...)
```

The type of key above is inferred as `string`, although I would've expected it to be inferred as `'a' | 'b'`.

Here's a [reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-brattain-bpir0) of the above.

Comment: Use `(Object.keys(object) as Array<keyof Type>).forEach(key => ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, this is by design? Is my only option then, If I want to have type validations inside my `forEach` function, is to cast the type manually again, as in `.forEach((key: 'a' | 'b') => ...)`?

Comment: You should not do `'a' | 'b'` since after `(Object.keys(object) as Array<keyof Type>)` forEach is aware about `key` type